# variable locking in python thread fails to lock if multiple lock instance created?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to threads and having a question..

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
s=0
lock =Lock()  ---->lock object position
def sample():
global s
for i in range(10000):
    lock.acquire()
    s+=1
    lock.release()    
t1 = Thread(target=sample)
t2 = Thread(target=sample)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
print s
```

This code gives expected result of 20000 as the operation on variable s is done atomically.

But when I change the lock() creation position, the locks are not working as expected. I changed like

```
 from threading import Thread, Lock
    s=0    
    def sample():
        lock =Lock()  ---> lock() added inside function
        global s
        for i in range(10000):
            lock.acquire()
            s+=1
            lock.release()    
    t1 = Thread(target=sample)
    t2 = Thread(target=sample)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    print s
```

With this change I am getting inconsistent values. So I am guessing the lock is not working here. 
Can some one help me to understand lock working based on this example?
Do locking only get honored if same lock object is used for both threads?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first version, the Lock is created before the threads are ever started and is a global variable available to both thread. Hence, this single lock object is shared between the threads.  The lock object will only allow one thread at a time to acquire it.  While it's been acquired, the other thread invoking `.acquire()` will block until the other thread invokes `.release()`.  And as you noted, your code works as expected.

In your second version, when you move the Lock creation into the thread function as a **local variable**.  Hence, each thread invokes a different run of `sample` which creates a unique and different `lock` object.  Each thread is always able to acquire the local `lock` variable without waiting because the other thread is always acquiring another lock.  Hence, the `s` variable isn't really protected.

Comment: But both locks are acting on a single variable 's' and the variable will have to lock irrespective of the caller ? @selbie

Comment: Think of it like this.  Let's say `s` is a house.  Anyone of us can enter the house via the front door and lock it from within the inside.  And when we leave the house, we leave the front door unlocked.   If you've got the front door locked, I can't enter it and change the furniture arrangement in the house - because we are both referencing the same lock (the one on the on the front door).  But if I suddenly decide to use the back door to your house, which uses a different lock, we can both be in the house at the same time.

Comment: Your first version is akin to a house with only one door and lock.  Your second version is akin to each person getting his own door (with a different lock) to enter the house.

Comment: and in second case, what I noticed is the output differs only a small.  If I didnt use any  lock, I used to get values around 15000 instead of 20000. But when I used wrong lock like shown in second example, I always get around 19970 [ only difference around 30] . I mean  comparatively better result  . So in second example,  I feel the variable is NOT  100% UNprotected like the case of no lock

Comment: The reason why you see weird and inconsistent results when not using a proper locking mechanism is because each thread is caching the value of `s` locally and deferring the calculated result of `s+1` back to memory however it wants. Both language and hardware CPU threading optimizations do optimizations that assume another thread isn't accessing the same memory.  Google for "cache coherency" if you want more details.

Comment: Thanks @selbie for the explanations! Accepted the answer!